Template argument deduction fail for parameter pack containing string reference
The following code example represents a simplified version of my code.
The code snippet contains a class called Command that I can construct using named constructors. When constructing the class, it requires a string that I would like to parse by reference to limit stack usage.
My production code contain many different types of the Command class that all derives from a base (omitted here for simplicity), so I have also created a templated 'instantiate' function that hides some of the std::shared_ptr boiler-plate code.
The problem I face is, that when using the templated instantiate function with a reference to a std::string, the compiler is unable to deduce the template parameters and complains about inconsistent parameter pack.
In the example main function I included calling the named constructor directly with a string reference, and also an example that calls an alternative named constructor that takes just a string.
I would like to avoid the named constructor that takes a string instance, so can anyone explain to me why the named constructor that takes a string reference fails when encapsulating it in a templated function?
#include <memory>
#include <string>

class Command
{
public:
    static Command* named_constructor_str_ref(const std::string &t)
    {
        return new Command(t);
    }
    static Command* named_constructor(const std::string t)
    {
        return new Command(t);
    }
    ~Command() = default;

private: 
    explicit Command(const std::string &t) : text(t) {}
    const std::string text;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...), Ts... args)
{
    if(named_ctr != nullptr)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(named_ctr(args...));
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main(void)
{
    const std::string s = "My text";

// Calling named constructor with string reference directly works
    auto c1 = std::shared_ptr<Command>(Command::named_constructor_str_ref(s));

// Instantiating with no string reference works
    auto c2 = instantiate(Command::named_constructor, s);

// Instantiating with string reference does not work... Why????
    auto c3 = instantiate(Command::named_constructor_str_ref, s);

    return 0;
}

The error message from gcc
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:45:26: error: no matching function for call to 'instantiate(Command* (&)(const std::string&), const std::string&)'
   45 |     auto c3 = instantiate(Command::named_constructor_str_ref, s);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:26: note: candidate: 'template<class T, class ... Ts> std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T* (*)(Ts ...), Ts ...)'
   24 | std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...), Ts... args)
      |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:26: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
<source>:45:26: note:   inconsistent parameter pack deduction with 'const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>'
   45 |     auto c3 = instantiate(Command::named_constructor_str_ref, s);
      |               ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


please include the error message in the question.

The problem is that your instantiate function tries to deduce the T from two arguments. First is named_constructor_* and the second is s object itself. If you have mismatch you get an error.

In
template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...), Ts... args)

Ts... is deduced from 2 places:

T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...)
Ts...args

With instantiate(Command::named_constructor_str_ref, s)
Ts... is deduced as const std::string& from the former, and std::string from the latter, so mismatching deduction, so a fail.
(It is the meaning of gcc error "inconsistent parameter pack deduction with")
You might

have separate template arguments:

template <typename T, typename... Ts, typename... Us>
std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...), Us&&... args)
{
    if(named_ctr != nullptr)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(named_ctr(std::forward<Us>(args)...));
    }
    return nullptr;
}
// or
template <typename Func, typename... Ts>
std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(Func f, Ts&&... args)
{
    if (f)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<std::remove_pointer_t<decltype(f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))>>(f(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
    }
    return nullptr;
}


disallow deduction

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
std::shared_ptr<Command> instantiate(T *(*named_ctr)(Ts...), std::type_identity_t<Ts>... args)
{
    if(named_ctr != nullptr)
    {
        return std::shared_ptr<T>(named_ctr(std::forward<Ts>(args)...));
    }
    return nullptr;
}


Thank you for your response. It doesn't sound like a good idea to disallow deduction, so I have tried your first two examples. If I deliberately test with a conversion that is not deductible, I like the error messages of the first example better than the other, so I will use your first suggestion.

"It doesn't sound like a good idea to disallow deduction". There is nothing wrong with that. Care should be done to decide which one is deducible though. All 3 choices are good.
